# Audio stops on refresh

Tags: javascript, html

And if it stops it won't autoplay on reload or opening the site like it should. Once it has stoped it won't even work when i restart the localhost server again. I uploaded my files to github to test if it is something with my local server. So the problem still appears and i have no clue how to solve it since autoplay is active. If someone could help out i would appreciate that. Thanks in advance !

I changed autoplay and loop in the index file to autostart="true" didn't work either so i sticked to autoplay loop. i added buttons to stop the audio if anybody wants to.

```
<audio id="background-audio" class="background-audio" autoplay loop >
        <source class="background-audio" type="audio/mpeg"  src="audio/videoplayback7.m4a">
      </audio>
```

```
var audio = document.getElementById("background-audio")
function belltwo() {
    
    audio.play();
}

function bellthree() {
    
    audio.pause();
}

website link : https://depressedunicorn.github.io/NiRiN/ if you want to test out the problem yourself
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah already found the solution ^^ but only works on localhost server now: i can now stop the audio restart the page and it will autoplay everytime. but not on github page maybe it takes time for the changes to take effect.

```html
<audio id="background-audio" class="background-audio" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
        <source type="audio/mpeg"  src="audio/videoplayback7.m4a">
      </audio>
    <video id="background-video" class="background-video" allowfullscreen="true" muted="true" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline="playsinline" loop="loop">
        <source src="/img/beepleloops/beepleDnB93.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```